# Removing trailing blanks from a file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I'm trying to remove trailing blanks at the end of every record in a text file using a shell script. Let's say I have the following columns in the file:

```
123 456 789' '   
234 567 890' '
```

Desired output:

```
123 456 789   
234 567 890
```

I tried `tr -d ' '`, but it removes all the blanks in the lines. When `sed 's/[[:blank:]]+$//g'` is used it puts together the records in the same line.

Comment: Could the file have the wrong type of line endings? Use `file [file].txt` and note the line ending type.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I'm amazed for the prompt response. I'll try that and get back to you on the outcome.

Comment: I did try but did not make it work. I get back:
sed: 001-3036 usage: sed [-an] [-C ccsid] command file … sed [-an] [-C ccsid] [-e command] [-f command_file] file … Any directions to go from here ? Thanks

Comment: Note that the OP [has said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/541896/80216#comment1005526_542061) “After further investigation I find out I was using an obsolete version of sed.  Once I target the correct sed version it run the way I was expected.  I used: `sed "s/[[:space:]]*$//g" input.txt`.  Thanks everyone…”

Answer (score 2):

For `GNU-sed`:

use:

`sed 's/[[:blank:]]\+$//g'`

instead of `sed 's/[[:blank:]]+$//g'`

(note the `\` in front of `+`)

If you don't want to use the *backslash* in front of the *plus sign*, you can use `--regexp-extended` (`-E` for short) with your `sed` command, like this:

```
sed -E 's/[[:blank:]]+$//g'
```

---

Update: the problem is that you are not using `GNU sed`; your `sed` seems to be [this one](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzahz/rzahzsed.htm).

For "your" `sed`:

try this:

`sed -e 's/[:blank:]+$//g'`

or maybe with double brackets too:

`sed -e 's/[[:blank:]]+$//g'`

(I just skimmed its documentation, but now, with this understanding and info, you should be able to craft the correct command for "your" `sed`)

Comment: +1 You don't need the `g` in your `sed` command.  `g` tells sed to replace every occurrence instead of just the first occurrence.  Since your pattern is anchored to end-of-line, there can only be one match.

Comment: yeah, that's right; I just tried to reassemble her/his original try as close as possible, to show exactly what went wrong, because the try was good enough.

Comment: -E expression not supported. I keep getting the error sed: 001-3036 usage: ... and using '\' in front of + it doesn't work either although I have no error back.

Comment: Ok, I know what is happening. You don't have `GNU sed`

Comment: You have this `sed`: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzahz/rzahzsed.htm

And not this one:
https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html

Comment: That make sense. I'll investigate based on that. Thx.

Comment: check my updated answer.

Comment: After further investigation I find out I was using an obsolete version of sed. Once I target the correct sed version it run the way I was expected. I used:sed "s/[[:space:]]*$//g" input.txt. Thanks everyone, it was very helpful the feedback I get on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

the way is

```
<input.txt sed -r 's/ +$//g' >output.txt
```

Comment: sed: 001-3036 usage: sed [-an] [-C ccsid] command file ...